# SWTBot eclipse - How to terminate (stop project) a running project

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, automation, swtbot

I'm trying to stop a running project using SWTBot plug-in (for Automation testing).
I've tried to terminate the project with the following command:

```
bot.toolbarButtonWithTooltip("Terminate").click();
```

but it doesn't work! also, I thought the problem is with element Focus issue, I fixed that with:

```
// Go to Console window (focus)
KeyboardFactory.getAWTKeyboard().pressShortcut(Keystrokes.ALT,Keystrokes.SHIFT,KeyStroke.getInstance(0, 'Q'));
bot.sleep(100);
KeyboardFactory.getAWTKeyboard().pressShortcut(KeyStroke.getInstance(0, 'C'));
bot.sleep(3000);
// TODO: try to terminate project
bot.toolbarButtonWithTooltip("Terminate").click();
```

but still it doesn't work!!

I also tried to use bot.Button() instead of toolbarButtonWithTooltip(), and also it doesn't work...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass an index instead of string to acces the toolbar button, or you could terminate from the Run menu:

```
bot.menu("Run").menu("Terminate").click();
```

Comment: Hi Andrei Pop, there is no 'Terminate' button under Run menu.. so it's not a working way to terminate the project... any other ideas ?

Comment: You need to make sure you are in the Debug perspective

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '&' at the beginning of your toolbar button string. Works for me.

```
bot.toolbarButtonWithTooltip("&Terminate").click();
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I got: "Couldn't able to terminate project - Could not find widget matching: (of type 'ToolItem' and with tooltip '&Terminate' and with style 'SWT.PUSH')". still not working.

Comment: Are you in the Debug perspective?

Comment: no, but now I switch it and it's working by the following code:

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution and it's working, I changed the Run to Debug Perspective, and after that selected the project form the tree and clicked Terminate...

```
AllTestSuite.bot.menu("Window").menu("Open Perspective").menu("Other...").click();
SWTBotShell openPerspectiveShell = AllTestSuite.bot.shell("Open Perspective");
openPerspectiveShell.activate();
AllTestSuite.bot.sleep(1000);
AllTestSuite.bot.table().select("Debug");
AllTestSuite.bot.button("OK").click();

System.err.println("after debug window");
AllTestSuite.bot.sleep(1000);

AllTestSuite.bot.tree().setFocus();
AllTestSuite.bot.tree().getTreeItem("Analog_input [C/C++ Remote Application]").select();
AllTestSuite.bot.sleep(1000);
AllTestSuite.bot.menu("Terminate").click();
```